# allow access to a .php file only from another .php file and not direct url

Tags: php, apache, http

I have two files stored in my local server in a folder, login.php and update.php. These two files are accessible from any location as long as they enter:

```
ip:port/folder/login.php
```

and

```
ip:port/folder/update.php.
```

What I am trying to do is prevent the users going to **update.php** by entering it in the url and only allow them to access the **update.php** file by first going to **login.php** (**login.php** redirects them to **update.php** when a button is pressed).

I am kinda new to php and apache. I am not sure if this should be done in PHP or in .htaccess file and how.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Well since you're new to php and you're using separate files without a router, the only thing you have to do is, on update.php check if there's is a session started, if so, cool just show the update.php if not, redirect the user to login.php, after the user post his info to login.php and they are alright you create a session and redirect the user to update.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION`

```
// Let's say this is you update.php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) /* or something like that */)
{                     
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}

// do whateven you need to do and set up $_SESSION variables 
// for example get the user entered info here

// This is how you set session variables
$_SESSION['username'] = ...;
$_SESSION['email']    = ...;

// Then after you did the registration part or something else you wanted to do
// You can redirect the user to any page you want
header("Location: some_other_page.php");
```

Every time user tries to enter the `update.php` right away, he or she will be redirected to login after they have logged out since the session is not there.

***Hope this helped a little.***

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have a URL that a user can visit only sometimes.

If you want a login system, then do what everybody else does:

1. Set an identifying cookie on login
2. When a user visits a restricted page:

   1. Test that you have identified them
   2. Test that the identified user is authorised to view the page
   3. Redirect them to the login page or give them a not authorised response if either of the previous two conditions were failed

Answer (score 0):

You can have it check the referral url. You can also create a user session,  so when a user accesses update . php, a variable is verified. The session variable can be set to a correct value on login. Php.

Sessions allow you to store variables as people go from page to page on your website.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this is with [readfile](https://www.php.net/readfile).

```
<?php
// This is the path to your PDF files. This shouldn't be accessable from your
// webserver - if it is, people can download them without logging in
$path_to_pdf_files = "/path/to/pdf/files";

session_start();

// Check they are logged in. If they aren't, stop right there.
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] != true) {
    die("You are not logged in!");
}

// Get the PDF they have requested. This will only allow files ending in 'pdf'
// to be downloaded.
$pdf_file = basename($_GET['file'], ".pdf") . ".pdf";

$pdf_location = "$path_to_pdf_files/$pdf_file";

// Check the file exists. If it doesn't, exit.
if (!file_exists($pdf_location)) {
    die("The file you requested could not be found.");
}

// Set headers so the browser believes it's downloading a PDF file
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$pdf_file");
$filesize = filesize($pdf_location);
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

// Read the file and output it to the browser
readfile($pdf_location);

?>
```

This was taken from [wildeeo-ga](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/519364.html)'s answer on google answers.